# How to design a relational database for associating multiple tags with id?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm developing a project of Q/A website, and a questions in this website can be linked with multiple tags.

For example: `How can I implement quicksort in C++ ?`

Tags for this question can be `C, C++, Algorithm`

My question is how can I store these tags in MySQL table ?

My approach:

The question above has `id = 123`

```
-------------------------
|question_id | tags     |
-------------------------
| 123        |  C       |
-------------------------
| 123        |  C++     |
-------------------------
| 123        |Algorithm |
-------------------------
| 124        | Java     |
-------------------------
```

But if I create a table in this sense, then for lot of questions, the table will become very large.

Is there any better and efficient way to store this kind of data ?

Answer (score 1):

Managing **Tags** in Information Systems can be done by two methods. And we have **trade-off** between **simplicity and low performance** and **complexity and difficulties and high performance**.

**First Solution**: Using TAG Table and many-to-many relationship between Our_Table and TAG table. (as @tadman describe)

**Second Solution**: 
If we want a very quick and high performance way to **retrieve** data related to specific tags, we can use **Bit-Mask Solution**.

**Bit-Mask Solution for TAG Management System** (previously described for similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440855/how-to-efficiently-set-subtract-a-join-table-in-postgresql/47508251#47508251))

In this method **we have same tables** (as @tadman said).
just add 1 fields, a `long` or `bigint` (related to our DBMS) into the table that wants to have TAGs (like `Question`)

This field shows TAGs of `Question` in **binary format**. For example suppose that we have 8 records in TAG table. 
1- some TAG 1 
2- some TAG 2 
... 
8- some TAG 8

then if we want to set TAGs 1,3,6,7 to one `Question`, just use this number 01100101. 
 (I offer to use reversed version of binary (0,1) placement to support additional TAGs in future.)

we can use **10 base number** to add in database (101 instead of 01100101)

**Then**, to find appropriate `Question`s for any given TAGs, JUST select from `Question` and use `bitwise AND` like below.

**A:** (shows the TAGs sequence that we are looking in Question, like 5 as 00000101) 

 **B:** (shows TAGs of any `Question` like 101 as 01100101)

```
select * from Question q
where A & q.B  = q.B
```

This query returns all Questions that have subsets of the specific TAGs.

We can use other functionalities of Bit-Wise operations like `A & q.B > 0` to return at least 1 equal TAG between `A` and `B`. And So on.

**Notice:** 

1: we have some **extra difficulties** when a new TAG is Added or to be Delete. But this is a trade-off. Adding or Deleting new TAGs less happens. 

2: we should use `Question`, `Tags` and `Question_Tags` Table too. But in search, we just use new field.

Comment: Bitmask:  Limit on `SET` is 64.  Limit on bitwise operations before version 8.0: 64.

Comment: Can you elaborate on BitMask approach?
Does not require having Id's for Tags of power of two, and limits our Tags to very small number?

Answer (score 1):

Have an extra table with exactly 3 columns: id of item being tagged, tag, ordering info.

When you add *or delete* an item, add or delete all the relevant rows from this table.

The details are here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists
Efficient, fast, easy, and highly scalable.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your tags compact, make the tags themselves a first-class entity, not just some random string column:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_on_label` (label)
);
```

Then have a small, simple join table between the questions and tags:

```
CREATE TABLE question_tags (
  question_id INT NOT NULL,
  tag_id INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_on_question_tag` (question_id, tag_id),
  KEY `index_on_tag` (tag_id)
);
```

Which should cover querying both what tags a question has and what questions a tag has.

Comment: How will it increase the speed ? I think joins make query slower. I'm not in favour of using joins,  Can you please clarify the answer more? or suggest an alternative.

Comment: The index size for a table that's pure int will be smaller, plus the storage size of the `question_tags` table is minimized with fixed-length rows. All of those are positive benefits. Putting strings in there is a good first step but if that's not scaling, I'd try this next. Think of how much work the database has to do to compare "Algorithm". It has to apply collation rules, deal with potentially multi-byte characters, and so on. That can get very messy.